# Is there a way to ask for multiple choices in a popup like messagebox do

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display a pop up the way message box do but rather then displaying two options (Yes, No) I want to have more than two options personalized as I want for example to ask  for his best color (blue, red, green):

```py
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import Button, Tk


def ask_multiple_choice_question():
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion(
        "colors", "whats your favorite color"
    )  # red, blue, green
    print(answer)  # print the color chosen


window = Tk()

Button(text="Submit", command=ask_multiple_choice_question).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built in option for this but one can be constructed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class OptionDialog(Toplevel):
    """
        This dialog accepts a list of options.
        If an option is selected, the results property is to that option value
        If the box is closed, the results property is set to zero
    """
    def __init__(self,parent,title,question,options):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.title(title)
        self.question = question
        self.transient(parent)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.cancel)
        self.options = options
        self.result = '_'
        self.createWidgets()
        self.grab_set()
        ## wait.window ensures that calling function waits for the window to
        ## close before the result is returned.
        self.wait_window()
    def createWidgets(self):
        frmQuestion = Frame(self)
        Label(frmQuestion,text=self.question).grid()
        frmQuestion.grid(row=1)
        frmButtons = Frame(self)
        frmButtons.grid(row=2)
        column = 0
        for option in self.options:
            btn = Button(frmButtons,text=option,command=lambda x=option:self.setOption(x))
            btn.grid(column=column,row=0)
            column += 1 
    def setOption(self,optionSelected):
        self.result = optionSelected
        self.destroy()
    def cancel(self):
        self.result = None
        self.destroy()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #test the dialog
    root=Tk()
    def run():
        values = ['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow']
        dlg = OptionDialog(root,'TestDialog',"Select a color",values)
        print(dlg.result)
    Button(root,text='Dialog',command=run).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the is is  valid answer but I need more elegant way to do this

Comment: @PentaKill: Explain in detail ***"more elegant way"***?

Comment: Hide the `OptionDialog` class away in a seperate code file and import it. That way you don't have to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: I need more elegant way to do this

You are looking for something like this:

```
class App(Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        for question in questions:
            question.choice = Dialog.ask_multiple_choice(self, question)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: its fine I can remove my comment if you want

Comment: @PentaKill: Feel free to remove your comment, but thats not my intention. I wanted to show you a **more elegant** api. For now it's only a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

You should use messageboxes from pyautogui.
like : pyautogui.confirm
installed from :
https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

```
    from tkinter import *
    import pyautogui

    global oknog
    oknog = Tk()
    oknog.geometry('1000x600'+'+10+10')
    oknog.title("Test pyautogui")

    def show_something():
        answer= pyautogui.confirm('Enter the option you chose:', buttons=['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C'])
        print(answer)


    btn1=Button(oknog,text="Show something",bg="yellow", fg="blue",font=("Arial Bold", 16),state=NORMAL, command=show_something)
    btn1.place(x=30,y=1,width=220,height=35)
    oknog.mainloop()
```